# Refinement of partition changes Darboux sums

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

[image]

I know how to set the problem:

$$\sum_{1}^{n}m_i(x_i - x_{i-1}) \leq \sum_{1}^{m} m_j(x_j - x_{j-1})$$
$$\sum_{1}^{n}M_i(x_i - x_{i-1}) \geq \sum_{1}^{m} M_j(x_j - x_{j-1})$$

Where $(x_j - x_{j-1}) < (x_i - x_{i-1})$ and $m > n $... number of partitions.

I just don't know how to prove those inequalities.

Comment: Try induction and use the properties of infimum and supremum.

Comment: @Philipp Did I set the idea of the proof okay or ?

Comment: What you wrote down is what you want to prove. I would suggest to start with the base case of the induction, namely a partitition of $[a,b]$ consisting of only two points. Make an example and just play a bit around to see how the infima and suprema evolve.